# How to use Avro to decode an InputStream with JsonDecoder?

Tags: avro

I am trying to process a potentially very large input, not sourced from a `File`, through an `InputStream` and deserialize Java POJO (records) out of it, using `ReflectDatumReader`.

While `BinaryDecoder` is fine, I believe `JsonDecoder` may be more human friendly, should we want to inspect the encoded data.

While `BinaryDecoder` has an `isEnd()` method, `JsonDecoder` does not. This how my code looks like if I use a `BinaryDecoder` (apologies if this is not how I should be using this, I did not find enough documentation on how reflection should be used):

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(MyType.class);
try (InputStream fromStore = Channels.newInputStream(/* very large, not a file */)) {
  var reader = new ReflectDatumReader<MyType>(schema);
  var decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(fromStore, null);
  while (!decoder.isEnd()) {
    MyType data = reader.read(null, decoder);
    log.info("Read: {}", data);
    ...
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

How can I achieve the same when switching to `JsonDecoder`?
Why does it even make sense that only `BinaryDecoder` has `isEnd()`?

It is required that the data from the `InputStream` will not be wholly read into memory, as it's too large (chunks are OK). It is not acceptable to write the content into a file first either. I found examples which use `DataFileReader`, which seem straightforward, but the input cannot be a file.